# Setup VPN to connect VPC to home network?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I'm not clear if this is possible, but here is what I'd like to do:

Goal:
Set up a VPN between my home network and my AWS VPC. A use case I'd like to have working:
Have a Lambda function write to a database, e.g. Postgres running on my home network behind my router. Think of some machine with 192.168.*.* address on my home network running Postgres

I have read the documentation and I wanted to confirm what it would require to make this happen. Assume I have a VPC with a Lambda deployed to it.

1. Create a Virtual Private Gateway for the VPC
2. Create a Customer Gateway for my home network.
3. Configure the Customer Gateway machine in my home network (e.g. Raspberry PI) after downloading the vpn connection file from AWS.
   I'm looking at this article for reference:
   [setup raspberry PI3 as AWS VPN Customer Gateway](https://hackernoon.com/setup-raspberry-pi-3-as-aws-vpn-customer-gateway-7432f653707)

Is this all that I would need to do? Do I need to use some 3rd party software in addition to this? Or is this not even possible?
Thanks

Comment: Is this a permanently connected VPC, or something you'll only connect occasionally? Can your home router establish VPN connections, and route appropriate traffic via the VPN and other traffic via the "normal" Internet connection? By the way, having your database separated from your application will result in pretty poor performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an OpenVPN server on an EC2 instance and change your SG inside your VPC resources to only allow access from your VPC CIDR block.

AWS provide an AMI for OpenVPN server : https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00MI40CAE/ref=mkt_wir_openvpn_byol